# Devexpress controls clear selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have the DevExpress controls within update panel and I need to clear selection on all of them from server side. Like `DdlDropDownList.ClearSelection();` but in DevExpress simple actions are handled differently.

ASPxComboBox
ASPxDateEdit
ASPxTextBox

Does anyone know the best implementation of required functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the Value property of those controls to null.

```
DdlDropDownList.Value = null;
```

Here's the documentation for those 3 controls:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBoxtopic
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxDateEdittopic
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxTextBoxtopic

Here's a sample that worked for me with version 9.2.  The "Clears" button clears the editor while the "Doesn't Clear" button doesn't.

```
<dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="a" runat="server" ValueType="System.String">
    <Items>
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="1" Value="1" />
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="2" Value="2" />
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="3" Value="3" />
    </Items>
</dxe:ASPxComboBox>
<dxe:ASPxDateEdit ID="b" runat="server" />
<dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="c" runat="server" Width="170px" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Clears" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Doesn't Clear" />

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a.Value = null;
    b.Value = null;
    c.Value = null;
}
```

Comment: @alexander: I edited to include a code sample that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
DdlDropDownList.Items.Clear(); or DdlDropDownList.Text = string.empty;
someDateEdit.Text = string.empty;
someTextBox.Text = string.empty;
```